# How to Get Checked Radio In Array using Java script in php my code attached?

Tags: php, javascript, loops, radio-button, checked

i am trying to get checked radio "id" and "name" as my radio name and id are same like 1,2,3... and so on

my code is here,

```
var selection=new Array(); 
 var allR = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var a=0;
  var b=0;
    for(var i=0; i<allR.length; i++){ 
        if(allR[i].type=='radio') { b++; }      
        if(allR[i].type=='radio' && allR[i].checked) { a++; } 
    }
var num=0;
alert(b);

for(var j=1;j<=b ;j++) {

  //for(var i=0; i<alr.length; i++){ 

    if(document.getElementsByName('j').checked) {
      selection[num]=j;
      num++;
      alert(j);
  //}
  }
}
```

in this code var "b" is the number of radio counts and in second loop i am trying to get checked radio in array and printing them too but it just print the total radio button but do not print checked radio ???

hopes for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
if(document.getElementsByName('j').checked)
```

to

```
if(document.getElementsByName(j)[0].checked)
```

as your control has name as 1, 2 , 3. not 'j', and j is your for loop initial, so it not need to be enclosed in single quotes.

as document.getElementsByName returns a collection. you should check element by 0 index.

Comment: [getElementsByName](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259) returns a [collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506), which is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment.

the block inside the first for loop can be:

```
for (var i=0; i<allR.length; i++){ 

    if (allR[i].type=='radio') {
       b++;  
       a += allR[i].checked; 
    }
}
```

but there are those who dislike depending on type conversion like that.